# Nginx directory disclosures?

Tags: configuration, server, server-administration, information-leaks, vps

I'm dealing with a minor information disclosure when using nginx with onions. Servervault.com might be better suited for an nginx question, but I'm not sure a lot of those guys understand onions or the importance of anonymity, so I'm coming here first.

`http://myonionsite.onion/directory/`

With `/` at the very end does not disclose any server-side info.

`http://myonionsite.onion/directory`

Without `/` at the end, returns this address in the URL bar:

`http://myonionsite.onion:18080/directory/`

`18080` being the tor forwarding port. My nginx server is bind to 127.0.0.1 so the website isn't public facing. The http error page (I think it's a 301) doesn't disclose any info beyond that, I don't think -- making this disclosure very minor but still I would like to resolve it.

I played around with rewrites like:

`rewrite ^/directory(.*)$ http://myonionsite.onion redirect;`

This kinda worked but I found it caused 302 errors with other elements on my site, such as `/logo.png` -- which I found bizarre and confusing.

What's the proper way to deal with something like this?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't apache? never seen nginx do this. apache definitely does that.

Comment: Lol, wow. I know you're used to dealing with stupid people asking stupid questions on a daily basis, but that's a little insulting.

Comment: I'm using nginx v1.12.0-2 in Arch, apache is not installed. And also the fact that I managed to successfully (but incorrectly?) redirect the `/directory` requests should be indication enough that I am indeed modifying the nginx.conf and using nginx

Comment: Yeah, I can reproduce this in 1.10 nginx and you may have been using nginx to reverse proxy to apache

Comment: So could this be a bug in nginx? Can you recommend a temporary workaround?

Comment: I don't think it's actually a bug, nginx is providing a correct URL, it's just that nginx thinks it *should* supply the port, as that's where the client *should* be connecting.